# Swapping 2 images - javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery

what I want to do is when one of the image letters is dragged over the green box their positions are swapped without affecting the position of the other images, could someone help me how this could be achieved?

this is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/28/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it's enough to change the image src:
http://jsfiddle.net/rhtjr/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".circles").draggable({
        revert: true
    });

    $(".circles").droppable({
        accept: '.circles',
        drop:function(e,ui){
            var x = $(ui.draggable).attr('src');
            $(ui.draggable).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
            $(this).attr('src',x)  ;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what Im trying to achieve is that the green box will be a blank box and to be able to place the letters over that blank box, kind of like a drag sort puzzle, do you have any ideas maybe how I could achieve this???